# How to tell if the current revision is the original?

Tags: 8, nodes

I want to display a different "Submitted by" message for content that has been updated, and thus has multiple revisions.

How can I tell if I'm on the original revision, or if there are multiple revisions?

Answer (score 2):

[`NodeStorage::revisionIds()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeStorage.php/function/NodeStorage%3A%3ArevisionIds/8.4.x) will let you retrieve all revisions of a node which will let you compare against the current node's version.

```
 // Retrieve all vids.
 $nid = 123;
 $node = Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
 $vids = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->revisionIds($node);

 // Does the original node's vid match the current node's vid?
 return (reset($vids) == $node->vid->getString());
```